# key error while selecting columns for dependent and independent variables in pandas list

Tags: python, list, dataset

I am trying to select columns, but keep getting key error.

I used this code:

```
X=bikedata['kms_driven','owner','age','power','brand']
```

I used this command as well to check for any indentation errors:

```
print(bikedata.columns.tolist())
```

Everything was fine.

But every time I am getting the same key error:

```
KeyError: ('kms_driven', 'owner', 'age', 'power', 'brand')
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
col_list =['kms_driven','brand','age','power']
X = bikedata[col_list]
y = bikedata[['owner']]
```

X will be your dependent variables and y your desired independent. Check if bikedata is really a DataFrame. If it is correct, sometimes is a kernel problem.

Comment: Hi. I did go through the links u suggested, but none of them addressed the KEY ERROR iam getting while separating variables. I used the same method to separate variables in another dataset but no such error showed up. Sorry I am new to this...

Comment: I edited the answer, that should work.